# assigning symbol to multiple <span> via JS with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span on page which is appearing via loop depending on the number of records in database table, so at times there could be a single span or multiple, exact number cannot be known and the span looks like this

```
<span class="add-on" id="goaltypeicon"></span>
```

Then I have a dropdown menu and based on the selection I need the span to show `$` sign or `%` sign

This is the dropdpwn menu

```
<select onchange="selectSavingOption(this)" class="input-xxlarge" id="saving_options"
        name="saving_options" style="width: 100%"> 

    <option value="weekly_savings_amount"> Set Weekly Savings Amount</option>
    <option value="weekly_savings_percent">Allocate % Of Weekly Savings</option>

</select>
```

This is the JS function that is being called `onchange`

```
function selectSavingOption(element) {
        if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_amount') {
            alert('amount');
            $("#goaltypeicon").html('$');
        }if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_percent') {
            alert('percent');
            $("#goaltypeicon").html('%');
        }
}
```

The above solution works, but for some reason it only works for 1 span. I guess the first span it finds, but it does not work for rest of the spans.

For example if there are 4 spans on screen, the display of `$` and `%` will work for the first span only.

I will really appreciate if I can get some assistance in this.  I need the solution to change span symbol from `$` to `%` depending on the selection.

value `weekly_savings_amount` should display `$`
value `weekly_savings_percent` should display `%`

Comment: Multiple elements with same IDs is bad idea. And this is example why it is not good at all. Not even talking about discouraged inline JS.

Comment: ID's have to be unique ! Choose a class-selector instead.

Comment: And [example](http://jsfiddle.net/j0qqm2kq/) how it can be done.

Comment: Same id for multiple controls is always going to cause such issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this : because you are using multiple elements and giving them the same id is not a good approach, because Id must be unique. So remove Id from your span else give  a dynamic name to span ID.

and in your script use class.

```
function selectSavingOption(element) {
        if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_amount') {
            alert('amount');
            $(".add-on").html('$');
        }if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_percent') {
            alert('percent');
            $(".add-on").html('%');
        }
}
```

Comment: You are always Welcome..  :)

Comment: @IshanDemon let's just say that if you start using jQuery, you should use all its benefits. Inline JS and these `if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value` instead of at least `var value = $(element).val();` are sad. Too bad noone took my code - as the result we are stuck with 3 answers with modified (but nevertheless not good) original code. By the way, am I missed something, or `$` and `%` should be set only for particular `<select>`'s `<span>`, not to all `<span>`s?

Comment: @Regent Yes you are right, but In the above ans. my aim was just to give the solution not a optimized solution because user who is asking the question might following this approach for some reason.

Comment: @IshanDemon I know the reason why asking questions people follow this or even weirder approaches - lack of jQuery's knowledge :) I'm still not sure whether text should be set for one or for all `<span>`s, but if even OP doesn't care about this, I should just leave it as is.

Answer (score 4):

As specified in the W3C, the ID-Attribute have to be unique in it's scope. (Mostly the shown Webpage). [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)

Your HTML:

```
<span class="add-on" id="goaltypeicon_<?= $i ?>"></span>
```

`$i` could be a counter (in your loop) if you want an ID at your span

Your JS:

```
function selectSavingOption(element) {
    if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_amount') {
        alert('amount');
        $(".add-on").html('$');
    }if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_percent') {
        alert('percent');
        $(".add-on").html('%');
    }
}
```

If the content of your span should not be updated in all spans you have to diversify your classes or choose another selector like `:first`, `:nth-child`

With the approach of a counter appended to your ID you can also choose a wildcard selector in jQuery:

```
$("span[id^=goaltypeicon_]")
```

This selects all spans where the ID starts with `goaltypeicon_`

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute should be a unique identifier for a single item on the page. Some browsers and libraries might let you select all the items on a page with matching `id`, but this isn't the correct use of the attribute, so you can't guarantee it will work as you expect in all cases.

Also, if all your `<span />` have the same `id` you are effectively creating a `class` (which groups groups similar elements), so it makes more sense to use a class.

e.g.

```
<span class="add-on goaltypeicon"></span>
```

This would change the handler function a little, like this:

```
function selectSavingOption(element) {
    if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_amount') {
        alert('amount');
        $(".goaltypeicon").html('$');
    } else if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].value == 'weekly_savings_percent') {
        alert('percent');
        $(".goaltypeicon").html('%');
    }
}
```

```